# Can Z3 give you in which order and how many time some functions must be called to arrive at a specific value?

Tags: algorithm, z3, z3py

I want to learn to use **Z3** and I'm trying to solve a problem which looks like this:

- I have three variables *a*, *b*, *c*
- I have three functions *X*, *Y*, *Z* which, when called, modify the variables *a*, *b*, *c* (e.g. *X* returns *a+4*, *b-13*, *c+1*)
- I want to know in which order and how many times the functions must be called to have:

  *a = V1*, *b = V2*, *c = V3*

Can **Z3** solve this kind of problems?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, it absolutely can solve such problems. Stack-overflow works the best when you "try" something concrete and get-stuck first. What have you tried, and what happened?

Comment: This type of problem can be approached by z3py. But it doesn't look to be very easy to write in such form, especially depending on the types of functions you want to allow inside `X`, `Y` and `Z`.  If you limit it to summing and subtracting, it would be easy.